# hoverIntent Problems

Tags: jquery, hoverintent

I'm fairly new to jQuery and I'm trying to set a hoverIntent on 2 different elements on my page. I got it to work on the first one, but when I add it to the second one, it somehow cancels out the first one. Let me know what I'm doing wrong or if there's a better way to format this code.

Thank you in advance.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".panel").hoverIntent(function() {
        $(this).children('.info').slideDown();
        }, function() {
        $(this).children('.info').slideUp();
});
```

});

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".panel").hoverIntent(function() {
        $(this).children('.info1').slideDown();
        }, function() {
        $(this).children('.info1').slideUp();
});
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".panel").hoverIntent(function() {
        $(this).children('.info, .info1').slideDown();
        }, function() {
        $(this).children('.info, .info1').slideUp();
});
});
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I needed. I will remember to group them in the future.